# Use Selenium Webdriver to get periodically updated content

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

As an example, the chat site [Omegle](http://www.omegle.com) always displays on its homepage the current number of users online, which I am able to extract with this python script using the headless `HTMLUnit` Webdriver in Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
driver.get('http://www.omegle.com/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id("onlinecount")
print element.text.split()[0]
```

The output is like:

```
22,183
```

This number is dynamically generated and updated periodically by a script, and I want to read just this dynamically updated content at intervals without repeatedly loading the entire page with `driver.get`. What Selenium Webdriver method or functionality will let me do that?

[This article](http://adam.goucher.ca/?p=1401) seems like a relevant lead, though it led me nowehere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is untested, but I think the following might work:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
driver.get('http://www.omegle.com/')
interval = 10  #or whatever interval you want
while True:
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("onlinecount")
    print element.text.split()[0]
    sleep(interval)
```

I think if you find the element after it's been altered, it will give you the new value.

Comment: Just as I found out that `time.sleep` works, I return to find this answer already posted! Accepted, and thanks!

Comment: I don't think the above answer is correct. If it finds an element and you try to access its contents after it is updated, it will throw a stale element exception very often.